# Volley code sending null values in android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I am using volley to send data to mysql database. Before sending the data I am logging it where I am getting data.But when I am doing var_dump in my php code I am getting null values.
This is my volley code:-

```
public void update_info(final String device_imei, final String magazine_id)
    {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPDATE_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                        Log.d("DOWNLOAD RESPONSE", response.toString().trim());

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
            {
                String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").format(new Date());
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(KEY_DEVICEID, device_imei);
                params.put(KEY_MAGAZINEID, magazine_id);
                params.put(KEY_PURCHASEDATE,date);
                Log.d("SENDING PARAMS",device_imei+magazine_id+date);
                return super.getParams();
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQ.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

I am not understanding if there is a problem in my volley code why is it logging the correct values.
And this iis my php code:-

```
require_once "config.php";

$con = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $dbname);

if (!$con) {
    echo "Connection Error".mysqli_connect_error();
} 

$device_id = $_POST['device_id'];
$magazine_id = $_POST['magazine_id'];
$download_status = "Yes";
$purchase_status ="Yes";
$purchase_date = $_POST['purchase_date'];

echo var_dump($device_id) . "<br/>";  
echo var_dump($magazine_id) . "<br/>";  
echo var_dump($download_status) . "<br/>";  
echo var_dump($purchase_status) . "<br/>";  
echo var_dump($purchase_date) . "<br/>";
```

The log I get is as follows:-
SENDING PARAMS: 359221060741339Shatayushi201504-05-2016
This is the response I get:-

> DOWNLOAD RESPONSE: NULL
>   
> NULL
>   
> string(3) "Yes"
>   
> string(3) "Yes"
>   
> NULL

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Your response not  proper json formate

Comment: @vinoth12594 please check my updated question which includes the json data in response.

Comment: That is not proper json formate

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your php code first. Use either postman or html form. then only you should try to test on android. Your PHP code does not return json. It returns php var dumps. To return json you have to call json_encode instead with associative array.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than  return super.getParams(); return your own params.